# MySQL: using COUNT DISTINT to count number of unique product ID's, filtered according to value shown in another column

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I'm hoping there's a really simple answer to this that I'm just not hitting upon...I am trying to roll some sales data.  The below code works but counts all unique product ID's (ArticleID) for each product group (Item) regardless of whether they had sales showing in the NetTY or NetLY columns.  I want to have two COUNT DISTINCT lines, one counting the unique products with values showing in NetTY and another counting the unique products with values showing in NetLY.

The sort of code I've been trying has been like:
**COUNT(DISTINCT s.ArticleID) WHERE s.NetTY >= 1 AS Products**
...needless to say it hasn't worked :)

```
SELECT
   a.Item,
   a.Rnge,
   SUM(s.NetTY) AS NetTY,
   SUM(s.NetLY) AS NetLY,
   FORMAT(((SUM(s.NetTY) / SUM(s.NetLY) - 1) * 100), 1) AS vLY,
   COUNT(DISTINCT s.ArticleID) AS Products
FROM
   Articles a
       INNER JOIN
   Salesandstock s ON s.ArticleID = a.ArticleID
GROUP BY
   a.Item,a.Rnge
ORDER BY
   SUM(s.NetTY) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a `CASE` statement but I'm not sure if that plays nice with distinct. I was thinking something along these line:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN s.NetTY >= 1 THEN s.ArticleID ELSE null END)) AS Products
```

Hopefully this work for you.